# Counting occurrences of specific words in a range of cells in excel

Tags: excel, text, string-matching

I want to sum the occurrences of specific words in a range of excel cells. Attached is my data:[image]

I want to check for occurrences of elements of column J in column A. For Eg:
I want to count how many times the words Alvaro Morata (cell J1) occur in all elements column A.

I am using this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN($A$2:$A$1152)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$1152,J2,""))/LEN(J2)))
```

However, this gives me weird answers like 68686.429

The column K in the image above are my answers. I am not sure how excel is interpreting it and how I can I rectify it.

PS: If I use find function in excel and type in the text of J1, I get two instances of J1 in A:A, but if I copy and paste from J1 in to the find function, then I get a 0 count. I can't really figure out the how excel is interpreting column K and why

A push in the right direction is much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&I1&"*")
```

put that in K1.

Then copy K1 to the rest of K

Comment: If I use find function in excel and type in the text, I get two instances of J1 in A:A, but if I copy and paste then I get a 0 count.

Comment: if your search strings are in J then use the formula `=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&J1&"*")`